# How to correctly display unicode characters in VS Code's Integrated Terminal?

Tags: java, unicode, visual-studio-code

As per title, I can't seem to get VS Code Integrated Terminal to correctly display unicode characters. They always show up as question marks (?) in the integrated terminal.

I've ensured that the files are saved with encoding **UTF-8** which seemed to be the only solution suggested across all the answers I've seen so far, but to no avail.

```java
System.out.println("A unicode check mark character is supposed to look like this: \u2713");
```

**Expected output**: "A unicode check mark character is supposed to look like this: ✓"

**Actual output**: "A unicode check mark character is supposed to look like this: ?"

Comment: There is a possible fix at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60330.  Does that work for you?

Comment: @Mark While trying to search for a solution to my problem, I did come across the site that you have linked. Sadly, it didn't solve the issue for my case :(

Answer (score 11):

In VS Code Integrated Terminal, type command: `chcp 65001`
Then it should display unicode properly.

Comment: It works. Could you provide a workaround to load this charset by default?

Comment: @keramat, what's your scenario? It did work on my VS Code v1.45+

Comment: @Marshal Windows 7, https://img.techpowerup.org/200803/capture.png

Comment: @keramat, doesn't seem to be any unicode issue to me in your screenshot?

Comment: What does this command do? Some context would be nice

Comment: @smac89, chcp is to change the code page, 65001 is a code page encoded as UTF-8 to allow working with unicode data in 8-bit environments.

Comment: I get `chcp: too few arguments`

Answer (score 1):

Since vscode uses xterm you will need to add a fallback icon font like FontAwesome mine is like this:

```
"Cascadia Mono", "FontAwesome"
```

This will fix it

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Some more information would be helpful, like where do you put this configuration?

Answer (score -2):

I suspect VSCode don't understand the syntax \u2713.
So, if you can find the character somewhere else, copy it, and paste to VSCode, then can can show correctly.
Thy some characters [here](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908) (Note: copy the graphical represent of the character, eg )

Comment: This does not answer the issue